# Should the tags [inner-models] and [inner-model-theory] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Right now there are two tags for questions about **inner model theory**: [inner-models](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/inner-models) and [inner-model-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/inner-model-theory). I can't see any difference in the type of questions being asked under these two tags. Should they be merged or made synonymous?

Relatedly, neither tag has a tag wiki yet. I'd be happy to write an initial one once this is settled.

Comment: I recall Andres saying something about it on tea.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/34/6/tag-mergerename-requests/

Comment: Yes, this came up before. In spite of the similarity of names, these are different things. Do not merge. (And yes, probably the "inner models" tag is not used as it should.) Go ahead with the tag wiki, though. Thanks. I never got around to writing one. I can help edit it after, if needed.

Comment: So inner model theory is not about inner models? Somehow I am not surprised :)

Comment: @Tobias: There exists an inner model in which the tags are identical, but we can show that this universe is not even a class-generic extension over that inner model, or any inner model in which the two tags are equal.

Comment: Thanks all! I shall get on with the tag wiki then. Cheers.

Comment: No, thank you. I made some edits to your draft.

Comment: By the way, you can (and should) use `[tag:tag-name]` to generate the links to the tag pages. It works in the comments as well. See, [tag:inner-models].

Comment: Thanks Andres! I'm just starting this stuff (Philip Welch is doing a seminar series on it) so your changes are very helpful in improving my understanding, as well as the tag wiki. Asaf: thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Benedict: I hope someone is LiveTeX'ing that seminar, and that I could read the notes!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh Nice to hear. Hope you enjoy it!